# Javascript in Unity for Oculus Rift

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, oculus

I just want to know, can I use Javascript to program items and a virtual reality world in Unity so I can implement it into the Oculus Rift? I need to do it for a research project. I would try C++, but I am better with Javascript.

Comment: There are 3 choices for programming languages in Unity: C#, UnityScript, and Boo. C# is not C++ and UnityScript is not JavaScript.

Comment: Which one, in your opinion is easier to code in? And will it be very useful like the tutorials where it shows people how to create object and create a video game environment? Thats funny, in the tutorials that I have seen, I thought you can code in javascript and JAVA. Also, this will be carried over to the Oculus Rift and I can experience the virtual reality once I am done with the code?

Comment: I personally have always enjoyed UnityScript (sometimes called JavaScript, but very different), but might consider using C# as well. C# can be advantageous because you can learn it by reading the .Net documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel confident in `JavaScript` then you should have very little trouble moving to `C#` for `Unity3D` scripting. There is a plugin for `Unity` to use the `Oculus Rift`. @jahroy is correct in stating that `C#` documentation is expansive and most of it applies very well to `Unity scripting`.

Here is a link to a tutorial. One caveat, it requires Unity Pro (I don't have a DEV kit, so I haven't tried it personally). http://paddytherabbit.com/unity3d-oculus-rift-plugin-setup/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! What is the name of the plugin? And it will work in the Oculus Rift as you say? No problems? Because I have heard people saying they had problems. If you have ever used OR and downloaded the things that come with it from the website, the program for the whole thing is C++, but I guess that is like the default language or something? Someone showed me the code for moving your head back and forth and other things on how it works and it was written in C++. I just want to make sure that I did not waste all of my time on this but will C# absolutely positively work for OR?

Comment: Note: This information is outdated, Oculus Rift support is now built in to modern versions of unity, no need of a extra plugin unless you want the extra platform specific features [from the SDK](https://developer3.oculus.com/downloads/game-engines/1.9.0/Oculus_Utilities_for_Unity_5/). Also it does not require a pro licence.

Answer (score 0):

A-Frame is a JavaScript Virtual Reality Framework built on three.js, and has been gaining in popularity: https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/core/

I've not tried it yet, but it sounds like it integrates well with Oculus.

Comment: A-Frame works fine with Vive, Rift, Cardboard, GearVR.